# Show child/nested attributes in ActiveAdmin index view column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to show the value of a nested attribute in ActiveAdmin.

My code is as follows:

```
index do
  column :code
  column 'Sales Agent' do |client|
    client.sales_agent.agent_name
  end
end
```

This gives me:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/client_branches#index

Showing /Users/constantlm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.4.3/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `agent_name' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work, because when I do the following:

```
index do
  column :code
  column 'Sales Agent' do |client|
    raise client.sales_agent.agent_name.inspect
  end
end
```

It outputs:

```
RuntimeError in Admin/client_branches#index

Showing /Users/constantlm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.4.3/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

"Peter John"
```

Which is what I would expect the first statement to do as well (referring to the "Peter John"), but it's not. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems that you cannot access the child attributes from the object passed to the view, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your records and start with new records. Additionally try adding

```
    client.sales_agent.agent_name if !client.sales_agent.nil?
```

Comment: Would be better using `try()` like `client.try(:sales_agent).try(:agent_name)`

Comment: ruby way using the safe navigational operator (`&.`): `client.sales_agent&.agent_name`