# ActiveAdmin display nested attributes on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How can I display nested resources on the index page in a column, comma delimited?

I have 3 models

**models/job.rb**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :company, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true

  has_many :position_type_joins
  has_many :position_types, through: :position_type_joins

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :position_types, :allow_destroy => true    

end
```

**models/position_type.rb**

```
class PositionType < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :position_type_joins
  has_many :jobs, through: :position_type_joins

end
```

**models/position_type_join.rb**

```
class PositionTypeJoin < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :position_type
end
```

I have successfully customised the form page so it now lists position types as checkboxes, current values I've setup are "Permanent, Full time, Part time, Contract, Internship, Volunteer".

What I'm struggling with, is how can I customise the ActiveAdmin index page so that a column appears with the heading "Position type" and then each job lists the position type values that have been assigned. For example:

```
+-------------------+----------------------+
|     Job title     |    Position Type     |
+-------------------+----------------------+
| Painter           | Contract, Part time  |
| Library Assistant | Part time, Volunteer |
+-------------------+----------------------+
```

I did see this syntax in a similar question but just couldn't get it to work for me.

[Show child/nested attributes in ActiveAdmin index view column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289138/show-child-nested-attributes-in-activeadmin-index-view-column)

```
index do
  column :code
  column 'Sales Agent' do |client|
    client.sales_agent.agent_name if !client.sales_agent.nil?
  end
end
```

I tried to edit that for my needs

```
index do
    column 'Position type' do |job|
    job.position_type.name if !job.position_type.name?
  end
end
```

The error I got was

```
undefined method `position_type'
```

I'm totally new to ruby on rails, so sorry if I am missing something obvious.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
index do
  column 'Position type' do |job|
    job.position_types.map(&:name).join(',')
  end
end
```

To improve efficiency of the SQL try:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    super.includes(:jobs)
  end
end
```

Comment: As the OP is iterating over `job.position_types`, so the scoped_collection should look like: `super.includes(:position_types)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `position_type` in a `job` but it has many `position_types`. so the right call should be `job.position_types` and iterate over them if there are many, or if you just want the first one `job.position_types.first`.

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that this will generate a N+1 queries, that should be addressed by eager loading the associations in `scoped_collection`.